# Can't edit images in divs css

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to build a website and I am making a collection of images that I want to be in a row with a margin of around 20 pixels (the images are in a div that is repeated for however many images there are). When I run the code the images appear in an weird configuration in that they seem to be layered. When I add 'img' to the div class the images then appear in a  column which is not what I want. I have created a very simple website example with three repeated images that I want to be in a row. In previous websites I have been able to make the images appear in a row (the way I want it to be), but now this simply will not work. I will provide my code. Any help would be appreciated :).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <body>

        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Updated correct CSS:

```
.image{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 333px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 50px;
}

    .image img {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%; *addition made by myself*
```

---

UPDATE
When I run the edited code and add 6 images the images do not resize. Is there a fix to this issue?

---

---

UPDATE Adding height: 100%; seems to have solved the issue. I will update the question to layout all steps in solving the problem.

Comment: Need to know what's the stylesheet `main.css`

Comment: The stylesheet is the 'css' part above

Comment: can you post the link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.image img {width:100%;}` 
so that the images will cover their entire parent div and won't be overlapped

```css
.image{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 333px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.image img {
  width:100%;
}

.heading{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <body>

        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This has solved my problem, although I don't know why I was able to achieve my desired outcome on my previous websites without this code

Answer (score 1):

Hello check if is ok ?

```css
.image img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 333px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.heading{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<body>

<div class="heading">
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/297/297449/a-cup-of-coffee.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```